# WebSphere app fails to start with JMS Queue

Tags: jms, websphere

I have an application that runs on JBoss AS7, but we have one client running WAS and have had a "port" running in the past, now it's time to validate the EAR on WAS again and the app bombs on start up with the following error:

```
[1/16/14 11:04:29:209 EST] 0000000b ActivationSpe E   J2CA0138E: The Message Endpoint activation failed for ActivationSpec jms/TRECS_INVC_ESCROW_ANALYSIS_ActivationSpec    (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB application TRecsEnterprise#lib/tee-invoicing.jar#EscrowAnalysisConsumer due to the following exception: javax.resource.NotSupportedException: CWSIV0757E: The destination TRECS_INVC_ESCROW_ANALYSIS_QUEUE) on bus TRecsBus was not found.
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.validateDestination(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.access$800(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation$PointToPointStrategy.connectToLocalMEs(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:1947)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.connectToLocalMEs(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaColocatingEndpointActivation.connectToLocalMEs(SibRaColocatingEndpointActivation.java:148)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.connect(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:482)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.checkMEs(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:367)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.timerLoop(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:326)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.<init>(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaColocatingEndpointActivation.<init>(SibRaColocatingEndpointActivation.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(SibRaResourceAdapterImpl.java:369)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateUnderRAClassLoaderContext(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:642)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:358)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(RAWrapperImpl.java:1097)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.activateEndpoint(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1742)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.activateEndpoint(MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startMDBs(EJBContainerImpl.java:5370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.startMDBs(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:878)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3588)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1163)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2160)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2165)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:995)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.sib.admin.SIBExceptionDestinationNotFound: TRECS_INVC_ESCROW_ANALYSIS_QUEUE)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.admin.impl.JsDestinationCache.getSIBDestination(JsDestinationCache.java:555)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.admin.impl.BaseMessagingEngineImpl.getSIBDestination(BaseMessagingEngineImpl.java:1524)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.validateDestination(SibRaCommonEndpointActivation.java:1581)
    ... 36 more
```

Which indicates the queue isn't on the bus, but it's there when I look in the admin console and in the server configs. Here is the relevant line from sib-destinations.xml:

```
  <sibresources:SIBQueue xmi:id="SIBQueue_1389887701656" identifier="TRECS_INVC_ESCROW_ANALYSIS_QUEUE" uuid="0485391EEB9BFABAC23D25E8" overrideOfQOSByProducerAllowed="true" exceptionDestination="$DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_DESTINATION" sendAllowed="true" receiveAllowed="true">
<localizationPointRefs xmi:id="SIBLocalizationPointRef_1389887701661" node="devredhat58-01Node01" server="server1" engineUuid="11CD8C2A94C906C7"/>
```

I've looked in the FFDCs and they are really just the stack traces, no real help there.

I am fairly certain this is a configuration issue, just can't figure out where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue or Topics in WebSphere AS must be associated with SiBus destinations.
You need to create destination for your Queue:

1. Find/Create SiBus for your Destination
2. Select Desinations
3. Create new Queue Destination

After creating your destination you have to associate it with you JMS Queue:

1. Open JMS resources
2. Find your Queue
3. Select a SiBus
4. Select created Destination

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, could you elaborate some?

Comment: OK, I actually had all of that, but the script I inherited had a small typo in the queue name.  So while your answer wasn't the answer per se, following you steps allowed me to find it.  Thanks!